# Facebook User to User Invite to App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I want to make a request so the user can invite a friend to download the app in the `Google Play` market.

It works, the request is sent to the `App Cennter` in the `Requests` tab.  The problem is that:

1. I had to use `Canvas Page` in order for the notifications to work. But I don't really want a canvcas page, I just want the user who clicks on the notification to be redirected to either `GooglePlay` or `AppStore`.
2. The notification says "$app: $name sent you a request." I want to modify this notification to invite the user to download the app or something.

**NOTE:** sandbox mode is OFF and the App hasn't been submitted for review.

Here is the code.

```
    String msg = "some message";

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message",msg);
    params.putString("to", friendFbId);

    WebDialog request = (

        new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(), 
                Session.getActiveSession()
                ,params))

        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                if(error == null)
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.label_completed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .build();
    request.show();
```

Comment: Have you enabled the "Facebook Login" or "Deep Linking" options under "Native Android App" in your basic settings?

Comment: Yes, those options are enabled.